# Why solc does not detect issue in this code?

Tags: solidity, solc, compiler

I wrote a sample Solidity code below: in function `call()` of contract `sample_call`, I make a call to function `add_car()` function of another contract `sample`, but this is a bug, since variable `v` is never initialized.

I assumed that solc should detect this issue, and complain, but in contrast it happily compiled the code.

Do you think that this is where solc should be improved?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.1;

contract sample_call {
    function call() public pure {
        uint a;
        sample v;   // v is never initialized

        a = v.add_var(0x22); // BUG HERE, because v is uninitialized
    }
}

contract sample {
    function add_var(uint a) public pure returns(uint) {
    return a + 0x55;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please report such issues to their github.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a runtime error but no compiler.

`v` is cast as a type `Sample`. So, it has Sample's methods, and you can do things like:

```
v = new Sample();
```

or

```
v = Sample(_sampleAddress);
```

Your contract does neither so `function call()` fails at runtime.

I don't think the `solc` team would consider that a bug. The static analysis group on the Remix team might consider it a useful suggestion if it's not already there. They raise all sorts of *potential concerns* about contracts that compile but possibly may not do what the author expects at runtime.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Access to uninitialized variables can be determined at compile time. And it is a nice feature to have.

Comment: It would be great if the compiler would suggest that there seems to be a contract in play it isn't instantiated by anything anywhere. It is "as designed", for now at least, so maybe it's more a feature request or gripe than "bug".

Comment: It is only an opinion but `v` is never assigned a value, using it in languages like C, Java, etc. is a warning. I know that solidity initializes variables to zero, but using variables without an explicit initialization is not a great idea: _Explicit is better than implicit_.

Comment: I agree It is what it is, but maybe it should not be exactly like that. So, yeah, I think the `solc` would reject it as a bug report but the idea has merit, so this could be part of a crusade to overturn the status quo and anyone wants to carry the torch.